# Training for 1.5 mile run

Tags: running, running-training-plan

What is the best training programme to improve 1.5 mile run times?  For reference, my starting point is about 9:30, aiming for 8:30.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add what program you're following right now? Then we can get an idea what, if anything, you're doing that's preventing you from progressing

Comment: no program really..  I've heard that 400m intervals are the best approach though..

Comment: So...you don't run at all and you can manage a 9:30 1.5 mile run? That's a 6:20 pace, that is quite impressive. :/

Comment: @JohnP "Impressive" depends on context. 9:30 1.5-mile ability is more common than you might think among "athletic and active" but not specifically "training" 15-25-year-old males, especially if they play the kind of football we Americans call soccer. Among couch potatoes, it's very rare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At that short a distance I'd say run more. First and foremost, you need your body to get acustomed to running faster.

So doing sessions of 400m and 800m sprints - about 0.25mile and 0.5mile respectively, aiming to get towards a pace at or below your goal pace will help.

Additionally, keeping consistant records and lot of practise will get you there quickly.

A plan like that below (with adequate rest) should help get you towards the speed you want:

- Mon - 3x800m
- Tue - 4x400m
- Thu - 3x800m
- Sat - 1.5mile

Answer (score 0):

On every day that you run, go for at least 30 minutes. When you do intervals, go for consistent pacing, not speed--quick but relaxed. Alternate between workout days and easy running/jogging days. Don't bother too much with speed work right now, for 1.5 miles you need to develop aerobic fitness more than anything else. **If you haven't been training much/at all, you should probably just do easy runs of 30+ minutes each for several weeks before adding intervals.** A typical mid to long distance (>= 1500m races, often down to 800m) training program will start with "base training" (easy runs only), then progress into alternating easy days and longer, endurance-oriented workouts, then add some race-pace and faster intervals. 600m-1000m is where "sprinters" and "endurance runners" overlap (in a grossly over-simplified 2-party model), so if you're going for 1.5 miles I would recommend approaching it as a distance runner rather than a sprinter.

For intervals, you might try starting 3-4x800m in 3:20-3:30 with 60-90 seconds rest. I got that pace range both by estimating relative to your race pace and by using [this pace calculator](http://www.mcmillanrunning.com/). McMillan's "steady state" pace would be good for some 2-3 mile runs to build aerobic endurance as well. Doing a few shorter, faster workouts will probably help you, too, but it's not what's most important for a 1.5 mile race.

**Finally, be sure to build up your mileage and intensity gradually to avoid injury.**